# how to access the Protected variable of base class in derived classes when try to achieve run-time polymorphism?

Tags: c#, constructor, polymorphism, abstract-class, overriding

> in this code i want to achieve run time polymorhpism and want to use
>   the width variable which i have defined in figure class for rectangle
>   and Square class(1 perimeter common for rectangle and Circle class for
>   calculating the area and perimeter  (basically want to increase the
>   Re-Usability Feature of C#) but i am confused how to do it.new to C#

```
    abstract class figure //base class
            {
               protected int width;
                public figure(int W)
                {
                    width = W;
                 }
                 public abstract int getarea();
                public abstract int getperm();
            }

         class Rectangle:figure
            {
                int  h;
                public Rectangle(int h):base(width)
                {

                    this.h = h;
                }
                public override int getarea()
                {
                    return (width * this.h);
                }

                public override int getperm()
                {
                    return (2 * width * this.h);
                }
            }

         class Circle:figure
            {
               // int r;
                public Circle() :base(width)
                {

                }
                public override int getperm()
                {
                    return (2 * width * width);
                }
                public override int getarea()
                {
                    return width * width;
                }

        }
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            figure f = new Rectangle(10);
            figure f1 = new Circle(20);
            Console.WriteLine(f.getarea());
            Console.WriteLine(f.getperm());
            Console.WriteLine(f1.getarea());
            Console.WriteLine(f1.getperm());
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define your classes a bit differently. You need to define the `width` parameter in each new constructor and then pass it to the base constructor.

```
class Rectangle:figure
{
   int  h;
   public Rectangle(int h, int w):base(w)
   {
      this.h = h;
   }
....

class Circle:figure
{
    public Circle(int w) :base(w)
    {
    }
....
```

Notice, that on your example you've instantiated `Rectangle` with just one parameter, but you will now have to set both height and width:

```
figure f = new Rectangle(10 , 20);
figure f1 = new Circle(20);
```

Comment: so each time i want to use the base class variable in derived class i have to declare it perimeter of derived class along with base ? @Ofir

Comment: If i understood you correctly then yes. you have to declare it in the derived constructor and pass it on to the base constructor. After all you instantiate the derived class so this is the place to define it.

Comment: Unluckily, constructors are the one methods that aren't being automatically inherited from the base class. In each derived class you have to manually implement constructor inheritance.